# Node.js promise property undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, xlsx

I was working on an app in Feb but since then haven't had much time to work on this project. All was working fine before my hiatus however I am trying to get this snippet to run again without errors so that I can pick up where I left off without spending 3 days troubleshooting this error again.

I am grabbing a google drive doc, piping it locally where it is edited and then saved in a subfolder. It also sends some mails at the end.

On line 80:25 I am getting:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'data' of undefined

and have no clue why, please could some fresh eyes point me in the right direction? Is it a scope error? I have also recreated token.json to be sure.

```
let getNewSheet = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    //////// START DRIVE DOWNLOAD SHEET ////////////////       
    const fs = require("fs");
    const readline = require("readline");
    const {
      google
    } = require("googleapis");

    const SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
    const TOKEN_PATH = "token.json";

    fs.readFile("credentials.json", (err, content) => {
      if (err) return console.log("Error loading client secret file:", err);
      authorize(JSON.parse(content), getLatestListFromDrive);
    });

    function authorize(credentials, callback) {
      const {
        client_secret,
        client_id,
        redirect_uris
      } = credentials.installed;
      const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        client_id,
        client_secret,
        redirect_uris[0]
      );

      // Check if we have previously stored a token.
      fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        callback(oAuth2Client);
      });
    }

    function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
      const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: "offline",
        scope: SCOPES
      });
      console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url:", authUrl);
      const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
      });
      rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", code => {
        rl.close();
        oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
          if (err) return console.error("Error retrieving access token", err);
          oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
          // Store the token to disk for later program executions
          fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), err => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            console.log("Token stored to", TOKEN_PATH);
          });
          callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
      });
    }

    function getLatestListFromDrive(auth) {
      const drive = google.drive({
        version: "v3",
        auth
      });
      var fileId = process.env.NODE_DRIVE_FILE_ID;
      var dest = fs.createWriteStream("" + appDir + "\\tmp\\feedbacklist.xlsx");

      drive.files.export({
          fileId: fileId,
          mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        }, {
          responseType: "stream"
        },

        function(err, res) {
          res.data
            .on("end", () => {
              //  console.log("Done fetching latest Drive sheet..");
              resolve();
            })
            .on("error", err => {
              console.log("Error", err);
            })
            .pipe(dest);
        }
      );
    }
  });
};

var path = require("path");
var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

let sendMails = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    ///////////////////////// START XLXS AND MAILER STUFF //////////////////

    const XLSX = require("xlsx");
    const workbook = XLSX.readFile("" + appDir + "\\tmp\\feedbacklist.xlsx", {
      type: "binary",
      cellDates: true,
      dateNF: "yyyy-mm-dd;@",
      sheetStubs: true
    });
    const SheetNameList = workbook.SheetNames;
    var rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[SheetNameList[0]], {
      raw: false,
      //  header:1
      defval: '0'
    });
    var raw = workbook.Sheets[SheetNameList[0] /* ,{header:1} */ ];
    //rows.tourDate = rows.tourDate;
    var today = new Date();
    today = today.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

    var dateYesterday = new Date();
    dateYesterday.setDate(dateYesterday.getDate() - 1);
    dateYesterday = dateYesterday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

    var dayYesterday = new Date();
    var days = [
      "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    ];
    dayYesterday.setDate(dayYesterday.getDate() - 1);
    dayYesterday = days[dayYesterday.getDay()];

    var dateTomorrow = new Date();
    dateTomorrow.setDate(dateTomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    dateTomorrow = dateTomorrow.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

    var dayTomorrow = new Date();
    var futureDays = [
      "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    ];
    dayTomorrow.setDate(dayTomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    dayTomorrow = futureDays[dayTomorrow.getDay()];

    //setInterval(function () {
    var filteredRows = rows.filter(eachRow);

    function eachRow(eachRow) {
      return eachRow["tourDate"] === dateYesterday && eachRow["feedbacksent"] === '0' /* || eachRow["feedbacksent"] === 'undefinded' */ ; //2019-02-17
    }

    if (filteredRows != 0) {
      for (x = 0; x < filteredRows.length; x++) {



        console.log(filteredRows[x].emailAddress);
        console.log(filteredRows[x].fName);
        console.log(filteredRows[x].tourDate /* .toISOString().slice(0, 10) */ );
        console.log("Feedback: " + filteredRows[x].feedbacksent);

        ///////////////////////////////////
        var index = rows.indexOf(filteredRows[x]);
        console.log("Index: " + index);

        const updateFeedbackCell = raw[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({
          r: index + 1, // +1 to adjust for header row
          c: 13
        })];

        // filteredRows[x].feedbacksent = '1'; changes var only
        updateFeedbackCell.v = '1';
        XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "" + appDir + "\\tmp\\feedbacklist.xlsx");
        console.log(filteredRows[x]);
        ////////////////////////////////////


        //// INSERT MAILER SNIPPET HERE ////
        var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
        //var config = require('./config/passW'); //turn PW back on !!
        var wtctLink = "linktest";
        var gReviewLink =
          "testlink";

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: process.env.NODEMAILER_SERVICE,
          // port: 587,
          secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
          auth: {
            user: process.env.NODEMAILER_USER,
            pass: process.env.NODEMAILER_PASS
          }
        });
        var mailOptions = {
          from: process.env.NODEMAILER_FROM,
          to: "" + filteredRows[x].emailAddress + "",
          subject: "Hi " +
            filteredRows[x].fName + ", how was " + dayYesterday + "'s tour?",
          html: "<p>Hi " + filteredRows[x].fName + ",</p> <p>Thanks again for us!",

          text: "Hi " + filteredRows[x].fName + "Thanks again for using us!"
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
          //check for console errors
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log("Sent status: " + info.response);
            resolve();
          }
        });
        ////// END MAILER HERE
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No rows/records to process for yesterday..");
    }
    //}, 10000); //86,400,000 for 24 hours
    //////// END XLSX and MAILER STUFF ////////////////
  });
};

getNewSheet(console.log("fetching latest drive sheet.."))
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log("sending mails..");
    return sendMails(result);

  }).then(function() {
    console.log("feedback mails sent");
  });
```

Comment: that would suggest that `res` in `function(err, res) {` is undefined - have you checked for an error condition in that callback (no, you haven't)

Comment: Yes, I gathered that res is undefined and I am trying to find out why as it was working as expected before, do you mean something like 

`if (typeof something === "undefined") {
    alert("something is undefined");
}`

Comment: Hang on, I found my problem, it seems to be because I am using .env variables. Changed to hard coded version and it runs. Sorry, I am no expert in node and still learning, sometimes it gets overwhelming/confusing coming back to a project, source control and commit notes are now truly understood!

Answer (score 0):

Use try/catch or .then ---> .catch pattern to handle this warning :
https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/aucwkd8b36-asyncawait-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning

```
getNewSheet(console.log("fetching latest drive sheet.."))
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log("sending mails..");
    return sendMails(result);

  }).then(function() {
    console.log("feedback mails sent");
  }).catch(function(err) { // handle unhand led promise warning
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not pass any thing in `resolve()`

example

```
function myAsyncFunction(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.responseText);
    xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So stupidly I wasn't calling my ENV variables. Set `require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'})` at the top of the page and it works now.